# Change Magento 2 REST API

Tags: rest, api, magento, permissions, magento2

Hey guys I wonder if anyone can help with this.
Now I am facing a problem at my company. We are developing a Magento 2 Community multistore for our customers.

The idea is to have several stores in the same Magento 2 installation, where each store is for each independent company. The problem is the integration with our ERP system. With the API REST we have full control in the installation, even if we are not with the admin master credential. if we run commands like this in postman: https://magentostore.com/rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria
we have all the orders in installation, all stores. So the companies with their credentials would have the same control and it is a very bad problem of security. The stores would have access to data from each other.

We have tried extensions for advanced permissions like Aitoc and Amasty but it's only works at a frontend level and does not take any effect in API REST. We know that Magento was not made for this kind of thing so my question is:

is it possible to change the API REST to filter the queries by store? and where can I find these API REST queries?
I'd thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

So you can override api calls using **webapi.xml** file in your module, Just point it in your service interface and change acl if you want. In your service interface inject the original one and add some your filter before calling original.

The second approach to write a plugin on OrderRepositoryInterface and add filter there (but first solution is better because this service is used not only in api so you may do not want to restrict all calls)